# vscode auto-indent after php tag?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, auto-indent

After typing the php tag `<?php`, I press Enter
[image]

What I expected
[image]

Editor auto-indent setting
[image]

So, how can I do that?

Comment: That's not standard PHP practice. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Download the [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) expension in VS Code and when you right click on the blank area you will find a
 [Format Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFFs7.jpg) option.

When you will click on it the first time it will ask you to set a default formatter for PHP. Select PHP Intelephense from that option. Then, each time you click on Format Document then your code will be formatted as you are wishing and your code will look more beautiful. And if you want your code to be formatted each time you save the file, then refer to [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cbrevik.toggle-format-on-save).

Comment: Thank you, I've installed PHP Intelephense, but this does not answer my question, I notice that what I expected is not correct, PHP code should not indent after PHP tag, it should start from the beginning of the line.

Comment: But that is not the standard code formatting

Comment: Start from the beginning of the line is the standard code formatting, see: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/, you can also take a look at Yii2 or Laravel, they all start the code from the beginning of the line.